# Store error when inserting values in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a problem when I use the function store with Laravel

```
$id = DB::select("SELECT TOP 1 Id_ReqCambIng FROM cambio_ings ORDER BY 1 DESC")[0];

  $archivos = json_decode($request->archivos_subidos);
   foreach ($archivos as $archivo) {        
    if($archivo->status == "upload successful"){
      $archivo->name;
      $archivo->uuid;

      $ArchivosCamb = new ArchivosCamb();
      $ArchivosCamb->id_cambioIng=$id;
      $ArchivosCamb->NombreArchivo=$archivo->name;
      $ArchivosCamb->linkArchivo=$archivo->uuid;           
    $ArchivosCamb->save();
```

I get this error:

> "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Comment: you are storing object instead of string  I think

Answer (score 0):

The status attribute has wich value common? Because you're comparing a string with a object

Comment: This is my Model:
class ArchivosCamb extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'ArchivosCambs';

  protected $fillable =[
    'id_cambioIng',
    'NombreArchivo',
    'linkArchivo'
  ];

}

And this is my Migration:
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ArchivosCambs', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->string('id_cambioIng');
          $table->string('NombreArchivo');
          $table->string('linkArchivo');
          $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: It is correct all columns are string in the migration?

Comment: Yes, but i found the answer, i need to specify the column like this:
$ArchivosCamb->id_cambioIng=$id->Id_ReqCambIng;

Thanks for all. Regards